# A random "Register" button appears on top of every page on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Today I found a random "Register" button appeared on top of every page of this(https://www.2mstraining.com) Wordpress site I'm managing for a client.

Someone else from the client's company tried to edit a page last week and I think he/she accidentally made this register button.

I tried to remove this button but couldn't find it's origin within the theme or within the wordpress codes.
[Image-"register" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4DKN.png)

Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: search on your theme files.also check if it's comming from a plugin

Comment: How have you tried debugging this issue? Have you tried disabling the plugins one-by-one to see if any of them are causing the issue? Its impossible for us to debug your WP installation when we know nothing about it :)